# The default unit of the simulation time in the simulation script in Unetstack simulator

Tags: time, simulation, unetstack

I am running an simulation script in UnetStack simulator using `DiscreteEventSimulator` platform. I was wondering, what is the default time unit of the simulation time `T` if I don't specify one, does the simulator consider it  in seconds? Should I specify the time unit?

for example:

```
def T = 18
simulate T, {
  :
  :
}
```

in this case, does the simulator consider the simulation time 18 seconds? or 18 ms or what?

Answer (score 1):

The simulation time is in seconds. All other units convert to seconds (e.g. 5.minutes = 300) with the Groovy extension to numbers to add units.